# error: `<<=` operator is removed. Use `key := { x.value }` or `key ~= (old => { newValue })`

Tags: scala, sbt

when I compile sbt code([Reactive Messaging Patterns](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/ReactiveMessagingPatterns_ActorModel.git))

it went error in build.sbt of
this line:

scalaSource in Compile <<= (baseDirectory in Compile)(_ / "src")

error msg is:
error: `<<=` operator is removed. Use `key := { x.value }` or `key ~= (old => { newValue })`.
See http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html

Comment: How to correct the sbt code to solve it?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you should do, and it contains a link with further explanations. Can you show your code *after* you have applied the fix the error message tells you to do and tell us what *exactly* doesn't work with your code *after* you applied the fix? Also, it would be good if you could write to the SBT developers or file a bug explaining what *precisely* you don't understand about that migration guide the error message links to, so that the SBT developers can improve the migration guide so that other developers don't run into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

According [sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html) you should change it as follows:

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

Comment: `:=` doesn't works to me, I use `+=` and it works. I think `baseDirectory.value / "src" ` will not return a Sequence but a single File object, so I need to use `+=` to append it.